# Como hacer que un menu, que cuando se seleccione una opcion cambie de color de fondo, de la opcion seleccionada

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

## ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy realizando un menú que cuando, se seleccione una opcion, cambie el color de fondo de la opción, no la opción seleccionada. ya utilice el hover pero solo me cambia la opcion. no hace lo que requiero. una opcion que estoy analizando es de encerrar esas etiquetas a en un div . Pero hasta ahora no me funciono. Espero alguien me pueda ayudar. Este es mi framento de codigo:

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active icon-eye" href="#">M</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-location-inv" href="#">r</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-mail-alt" href="#">M</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-doc-text-inv" href="#">Re</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-bullseye" href="#">Ge</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-lifebuoy" href="#">C</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-train" href="#">Re</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-users" href="#">P</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-check" href="#">T</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-comment" href="#">N</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-user" href="#">U</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-truck" href="#">U</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas buscando de no cambiar el codigo que ya tenes y queres hacer lo que muestra la imagen, como alternativa podrias utilizar border-top y border-bottom dejo el ejemplo:

```css
      .navbar-nav{
      margin-top:20px;
      }
      .nav-item {
        background: #333;
        padding: 10px;
        color:#fff;
      }
      .nav-item:hover {
        border-top: 3px solid red;
        border-bottom: 3px solid red;  
      }
```

```html
<div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link active icon-eye" href="#">M</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-location-inv" href="#">r</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-mail-alt" href="#">M</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-doc-text-inv" href="#">Re</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-bullseye" href="#">Ge</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-lifebuoy" href="#">C</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-train" href="#">Re</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-users" href="#">P</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-check" href="#">T</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-comment" href="#">N</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-user" href="#">U</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-truck" href="#">U</a>
          </div>
```

Espero que te ayude! 
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El color de fondo se cambia con la propiedad [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-color). Con [`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/color) cambiás el color del texto.

```css
.nav-item:hover {
 color: #f00;
 background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
  <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active icon-eye" href="#">M</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-location-inv" href="#">r</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-mail-alt" href="#">M</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-doc-text-inv" href="#">Re</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-bullseye" href="#">Ge</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-lifebuoy" href="#">C</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-train" href="#">Re</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-users" href="#">P</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-check" href="#">T</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-comment" href="#">N</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-user" href="#">U</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-truck" href="#">U</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Si lo que querés es modificar el color del fondo de la sección activa, podes usar la clase [`.active`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#nav) de Bootstrap y modificar ese CSS:

```css
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: no requiero eso, si no requiero que cuando se seleccione esa opción cambie el fondo no la selección

Comment: Cuando pasas por arriba de una letra el color del fondo cambia a azul. Si no es eso, por favor volve a redactar la pregunta o poné algún ejemplo porque no se entiende.

Comment: agregue una imagen, mira la opcion que estoy utilizando es encerrar en un div, pero no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo otra opción donde se agrega un span dentro de la tag a y podes obtener un resultado similar.

```css
  .nav-item{
        display: grid;
        float: left;
        color:#fff;
      }
      .nav-item:hover{
        background: red;
        display: grid;
        padding: 4px 0;
      }
      .nav-item span {
        background: #333;
        padding: 10px;
      }
```

```html
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
          <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link active icon-eye" href="#"><span>M</span></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-location-inv" href="#"><span>r</span></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-mail-alt" href="#"><span>M</span></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-doc-text-inv" href="#"><span>Re</span></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-bullseye" href="#"><span>Ge</span></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-lifebuoy" href="#"><span>C</span></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-train" href="#"><span>Re</span></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-users" href="#"><span>P</span></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-check" href="#"><span>T</span></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-comment" href="#"><span>N</span></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-user" href="#"><span>U</span></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link icon-truck" href="#"><span>U</span></a>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Espero que te sirva algunas de las opciones.
Saludos!